# I want my website language code to show up in the URL?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have a website made in codeigniter. It's a MultiLingual site with about 9 languages . Basically the language change is done through cookies, so its better that for a specific visitor , whetever language last set in his cookies will be the language shown to him. But The problem is that I want to show the language code in the url, On each moment language changes, Hench cookies changes and the language code should also jump up to the URL this:

```
www.mysite.com/en/contoller/function             (en from cookies)
www.mysite.com/fr/contoller/function             (fr from cookies)
www.mysite.com/cn/contoller/function             (cn from cookies)
```

Even I want to show language code on Home Page.

```
www.mysite.com/en
```

Friends, how can that be possible? I've read a lot of stuff, but couldn't find a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried with the `$routes`? Open the /application/config/routes.php and set the rules:

```
$routes['([a-zA-Z]+)/(:any)'] = '$2';
```

It should do the work too:

```
$routes['([a-zA-Z]{2})/(:any)'] = '$2';
```

I had not tried this:

```
$routes[(en|fr|es)/(:any)'] = '$1';
```